# Object {path} is not a mountable filesystem

Tags: linux, fedora, filesystems, partition

I'm using Fedora 26 and I have 2 disks. One of them has 2 partitions

/dev/sdb : 30GB
/dev/sdb1 : 20GB
/dev/sdb2 : 10GB

I'm trying to mount the partitions using this command:
`udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1`

I get this error:

```
`Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1 is not a mountable filesystem.`
```

How can I fix this?

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 25 GiB, 26843545600 bytes, 52428800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6092c6a8

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  2099199  2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 52428799 50329600  24G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb6a8a9cf

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       41943040 62914559 20971520  10G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-root: 21.5 GiB, 23081254912 bytes, 45080576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-swap: 2.5 GiB, 2684354560 bytes, 5242880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           2.0G  4.2M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-root   22G  5.4G   15G  27% /
tmpfs                           2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                       976M  128M  781M  15% /boot
tmpfs                           393M   16K  393M   1% /run/user/1001
```

**lsblk -o name,fstype**

```
NAME                   FSTYPE
sda                    
├─sda1                 ext4
└─sda2                 LVM2_member
  ├─fedora_fedora-root ext4
  └─fedora_fedora-swap swap
sdb                    
├─sdb1                 
└─sdb2                 
sr0                    iso9660
```

**file -s /dev/sdb1**

```
/dev/sdb1: data
```

Comment: Please post the result of `file -s /dev/sdb1`. Also, *where* is `/dev/sdb1` supposed to be mounted?

Comment: @AlexP Added the output.  /dev/sdb1 is supposed to be mounted on /mnt

Comment: It seems that `/dev/sdb1` does not contain a known file system. What file system is it supposed to be formatted with?

Comment: @AlexP I fixed the issue. Added an answer

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved!

I used `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` and `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb2` to change the filesystem type of the partitions, then mounted them with these commands:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt2
```